# Multiple UIWindows status bars conflict

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, statusbar

I have two UIWindows and I need to hide status bar of top window and show status bar of bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I fixed my problem by making my top UIWindow height small.